# Multiple footer lines in metropolis beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, logos, beamer-metropolis

How could we add an extra much wider line, with the same colour background of the header,  so as to include the institution's logo at the bottom right-hand side of the slide?

The adjusted footer so far is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{\insertshortauthor~(\insertshortinstitute)\hfill\insertshorttitle}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=gray}

\author{names}
\institute{institute}
\title{Quack}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could redefine the fooline like the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{\insertshortauthor~(\insertshortinstitute)\hfill\insertshorttitle}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
%\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=gray}

\author{names}
\institute{institute}
\title{Quack}

\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=black!2, bg=mDarkTeal}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth, sep=1ex]{footline}
        \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
        \usebeamertemplate*{frame footer}
        \hfill%
        \raisebox{-2ex}{\includegraphics[height=6ex]{example-image-duck}}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]